# Page doesn't load - Wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables

I have following code, but my page doesn't load anymore. What is wrong?

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'menu.php');
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'getuser.php');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ffd_load_scripts' );

function ffd_load_scripts()
{
    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

    $arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
        );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
}
```

Previously it worked fine, the problem is given by the $arguments I think. Tried some things but still have this issue.

The problem is located in this part:

```
$arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
        );
```

When I use this code, everything works fine, but I really need the iterator:

```
function ffd_load_scripts()
{
    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

    /*$arguments = array();
    for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue['fieldcount']; $i++)
    {
        $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
    }*/

    wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo'],
            'index1' => $myoptionValue['id1'],
            'index2' => $myoptionValue['id2']
            )
        );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
}
```

Comment: Anything in your error logs?

Comment: Nope nothing, I checked with firebug. Edited the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in your server error logs. i.e if cPanel, then in the file "error_log" in your root directory.

Comment: no errors in the log

Comment: Updated OP again with code that works, but I really need the iterator.

Comment: The iterator by itself works fine, what is the output of `print_r($myoptionValue)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60317/discussion-between-telford-computer-doctorltd-and-stijn26).

Answer (score 0):

Should `$myoptionValue[fieldcount]` not be `$myoptionValue['fieldcount']`?

```
$arguments = array();
for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue['fieldcount']; $i++)
{
    $arguments['index'.$i] = $myoptionValue['id'.$i];
}

wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', merge_array(array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'idinfo' => $myoptionValue['idinfo']),$arguments)
    );
```

Comment: Everyone says that, but it works either way (in other context), anyway, I updated it with the quotes, still have the problem.